# Typescript does not detect properties which should not be there

Tags: typescript

I have a function which is formatting data, and the "values" within this data are well-defined. However, when mapping these values, TS is not picking up on new properties which are invalid. The problem is best explained with code (see the comments in the code):

[Here is the playround](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhAewBCB7eA1AhgGwK7QF4oBvAWACgopgFgAuKAZ2ACcBLAOwHMBuCgXwqhIsWqnhQiZSlABuOfIwZxE4rHggBtALp9yg8sOgAlCI1zZgkkhSoszF+k1acuUAD5QUAIwBWEAGNgPQMKAJQOZiguCGAYAAsIdXxrAAoASgZTc0tJAD4oVOIoexynAHIEtkYocIBbMygAMxYUOqhMWvi2bAATKDBWgLNGADpyqH50vTCIqKaUFjrMOLE0NJpEbzRlNfhM0VV1ggLpKnDIq2LSx0nrGLjE5IgMvXO5q0W2Lk4cZ+tNsBtvBRvINIxNAAGXQUWxQNhNQpGFCIm65AgYqDlHz+ILldI2GTvS4dFgsawAQTJmBAo2qVJYNNSaOABIA-CUHLkGJoWTCiZzgLgWBxCVRxVBRlLAcCADRwiVgxQMTBk0bLMDMxonMUS8X2IUikhQBV6qgLFAMcreVXlWVQAD0DqgAHd4iAoL0UI1gN0ahwUFZfa0XR1RRAyYtTWbAQxSqNAR5PF8fhw-goIAnaPKBRL+G89VNTQYqKEZAbhaKzuKpVmtmgc4qM0ooJpitHJVKU79sM97R2LVabSw7Y7nd5cEG-V4ONAvWY2R3Y1AAMoubhasoE4vaOEGfhAA)

```
type TextBoxValue = {
  text: string;
}
type TextBox = {
  values: TextBoxValue[];
}
type Result = {
  result: string | object;
}

const getTheValue = (): Result => ({ result: 'This comes from a child process.' });

const formatTextBox = (textbox: TextBox): TextBox => {
  const { result } = getTheValue();
  const originalValue = textbox.values[0];

  if (typeof result === 'object') {
    const arr = Array.isArray(result) ? result : [result];
    return {
      ...textbox,
      values: arr.map(res => {
        return { 
          foo: 'bar', // why does this not throw an error
          text: res.text || originalValue.text,
        };
      })
    }
  }

  return {
    ...textbox,
    values: [{ 
      ...originalValue, 
      foo: 'bar', // but this one does?
      text: String(result) 
    }]
  }
}
```

I know I can use `satisfies` and other techniques to get the error I want, but I'm curious why TS does not pick up on the invalid property with the code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your map is returning an object of type `{ foo: string, text: string }` which sufficiently overlaps with `TextBoxValue` to keep the compiler happy (but it will treat it as an array of `TextBoxValue`s).

That `foo` value will not show in any of the type hints and attempting to reach it with (for example) `const v = result.values[0].foo` will generate a `Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'TextBoxValue'` error.

If you use a type declaration in the map it will show the error

```
values: arr.map(res => {
  // declare type
  const textBoxValue: TextBoxValue  =  { 
  // Error: Type '{ foo: string; text: any; }' is not assignable to type 'TextBoxValue'.
    foo: 'bar', 
    text: res.text || originalValue.text,
  };
  return textBoxValue;
})
```

Similarly, if you use a `type assertion` in the final return, you're telling the compiler "trust me ... it's a TextBoxValue" and as long as there is enough overlap to satisfy `TextBoxValue`, it will stop complaining.

```
return {
    ...textbox,
    values: [{ 
      ...originalValue, 
      foo: 'bar', // No more whining
      text: String(result)
    // assert that I'm a `TextBoxValue` 
    } as TextBoxValue]
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It still doesn't quite make sense to me how the array literal (lower in the code) triggers the error yet the return value from `.map` does not. I'll commit your answer to memory and learn to accept this nuance. Also, for anybody who finds this, you can use `satisfies` to force the error as shown here: https://shorturl.at/lmrIV

Comment: Not easy. I still have to pause and think. Easiest for me is to imagine what the compiler is doing. In the map you create a valid object and returning it causes the type checker to see if it overlaps enough. In the final return it knows exactly what is expected and will complain. If you assigned that return object to a variable and returned the variable, no error. Personally I want the complaining. Makes me more diligent with my code